# Switch among different templates/views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to propose two layouts (ie, `horizontal` and `vertical`) for my contents. So switching in the selector will lead automatically to the corresponding layout. My current [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/luzuzin/1/edit?html,output) cannot accomplish this switching:

```
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="horizontal.tpl">
        {{one}}, {{two}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="vertical.tpl">
        {{one}}<br>{{two}}
    </script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: "vertical.tpl"
            })
    }]);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.one = "one";
        $scope.two = "two";
        $scope.layouts = ["horizontal", "vertical"];
        $scope.$watch('layout', function () {
            $state.go('entry'); // need to amend this such that changing "layout" leads to different template
        })
    }])
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="layout" ng-options="x for x in layouts"></select>
    <br><br>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Additionally, I hope the solution would NOT display the layout information in the URL; users can only see and choose layout in the web page. Moreover, I don't want a solution by SHOWING/HIDING `<ui-view="horizontal"></ui-view>"` or `<ui-view="vertical"></ui-view>` based on the selection. I would prefer a solution that passes layout information to states to choose the corresponding template (but without disclosing it in URL).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use a non-url parameter such as `layout`.
- Choose the template using a `templateUrl` function.

  ```
  app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('entry', {
              url: '/',
              params: { layout: 'vertical' },
              templateUrl: function(params) { 
                return params.layout + ".tpl";
              }
          })
  }]);
  ```

then you can switch using `state.go` or `ui-sref`

`ui-sref="entry({ layout: 'horizontal' })"`

Comment: It works, here is [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/luzuzin/6/edit?html,output) as record...

Comment: nice example.  One thing to note: the state will be fully *reloaded*, including any resolves.